# C++ munmap_chunk error with a specific 3rd party lib

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, memory-leaks, googletest

I am working with a 3rd party lib on Linux C++. Let's call it `liba.so` here. The environment is

- CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
- gcc 7.3.1
- gtest 1.8.0

With a minimal code snippet and a quick test case like the following, the test case would have memory corruption.

```
#pragma once

#include <istream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace mm
{
class Config
{
public:

        Config(std::istream& is)
        {
                for (std::string line; std::getline(is, line); )
                {
                        const std::string::size_type index = line.find('.');

                        if (std::string::npos == index)
                        {
                                valueMap[line] = line;
                        }
                }
        }

private:

        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> valueMap;
};
}
```

I compile this into my `libCommon.so` file; then I have a simple test case like:

```
#include <Config.hpp>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace mm
{
        TEST(ConfigTest, DummyCase)
        {
                // some random call to make a.so linked
                A::doAnything();
    
                // config
                std::stringstream css;
                css << "AutoStop" << std::endl;

                std::shared_ptr<Config> config(new Config(css));
        }
}
```

With the above code, on linking the test executable with both my `libCommon.so` and the `liba.so`, run it, I can get memory corruption. Running on valgrind, I could see the std::unordered_map operator [] immediately call into the `liba.so` memory space, and a legit memory corruption.

```
==2369== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2369==    at 0x4C2B16D: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==2369==    by 0x5DD5048: std::_Hashtable<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_M_insert_unique_node(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, true>*) (in /usr/local/lib/liba.so)
==2369==    by 0x5DD51EA: std::__detail::_Map_base<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>, true>::operator[](std::string const&) (in /usr/local/lib/liba.so)
==2369==    by 0x6005A50: std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::operator[](std::string const&) (unordered_map.h:976)
==2369==    by 0x60056F2: mm::Config::Config(std::istream&) (Config.cpp:16)
```

*However*, if I compile the whole above under Ubuntun 18.04 LTS + gcc 7.5, the problem is gone.

Does this sound more like the lib has issue or some bug in gcc 7.3.1 ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: libCommon.so and liba.so are built with different runtimes.

Comment: @273K Do you mean the glibc versions used for compiling libCommon.so and liba.so are different?